# echo var into wp_query

Tags: php, wp-query, variables

Im trying to echo out a value grabbed from a ACF field but I think im doing something wrong, could someone help me?

```
    <div class="news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                    $selected_cat = get_field( 'select_new_category_for_page' );
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'post',  'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => $selected_cat);
                    $Query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
                    <?php if ( $Query->have_posts() ) : while ( $Query->have_posts() ) : $Query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
                <div class="box">
                    <h2>Latest News</h2>
                    <h3><?php echo the_time('F, y')?></h3>
                    <p><?php $str = get_the_content(); ?>
                    <?php echo substr($str, 0, 100); ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read More...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im trying to echo the var $selected_cat into my $args for wp_query

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cat" variable need to be an ID of the category. It depends how you configured the ACF field in the backend.

Maybe you should print_r($selected_cat) to see what's inside the variable. it is probably an array with the full information of the category.

Comment: Yup just your right I clicked return object instead of ID

Comment: @GuruTom can you mark this as answered?